# How can I use my fourth gen IPod classic to play podcast episodes in correct chronological order?

Tags: ipod, podcasts

The default order when I download podcast episodes to my IPod is reverse chronological, such that the most recent episode plays first. I'd like my podcasts to play in correct chronological order, such that the oldest episode plays first. I have tried:

- Pressing play on the podcast folders on the IPod rather than individual episodes
- Going into my Mac's podcast app to change the settings on individual podcasts to play in sequential order
- Setting individual podcasts to custom play settings, changing episode order to "oldest to newest"
- Creating my own podcast station, setting station's play setting to "oldest to newest"

After each of the last three steps, I would remove my podcasts, sync, add them again with the new settings, and sync. The IPod still plays the most recent episode first. Many suggestions I see when you google this question involve using playlists, which no longer exist in the current podcasts app for Mac. Ditto the title.